# How do I debug javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging

On my page this link isn't working.

```
<a id="dnn_ctr1587_EditEventsCalendar_cmdUpdateReturn" title="Update &amp; Return" class="CommandButton" href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("dnn$ctr1587$EditEventsCalendar$cmdUpdateReturn", "", true, "", "", false, true))'>Update &amp; Return</a>
```

How do I debug to figure out what field is stopping this code from submitting so I can fix the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome worked best for me:

1. I clicked the wrench in the upper right.
2. I went to tools --> JavaScript Console
3. Above the sourcecode view is a dropdown listing files. I searched through each file for `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions` (I had to hit enter in the search box on each file to get the search results to refresh)
4. It ended up in ScriptResource.axd line 29 was returning false. I looked in the watch window and was able to see the name of the control firing the error.

P.S. initially I tried debugging with FireFox. The javaScript was showing all on one line. Chrome showed it nicely indented so I could tell what was going on.